# How to buy a notebook without windows preinstalled, no windows key on keyboard, AMD processor NOT Intel, with AMD graphic card?

Tags: laptop

I searching for a laptop with AMD processor AMD Graphic card, No windows, No windows key on left, SSD (or hybrid SSD+HDD) I pay with Bitcoin up to 3000 USD.

Any recommendation? I find not a single laptop without the Windows Key or Windows preinstalled.

Comment: The key is a simple sticker why not remove it yourself, and use cleaner or rubbing alcohol to remove the sticky? Erasing the hard drive with gparted or similar, take a couple minutes at most.  Why go through all the effort to find that 1 in a million laptop, if it even exists, when at least these 2 parts of your requirements are so easy for you to do manually?  How about buying whatever, and paying a local computer store or even a smart friend say $50  to do it for you?

Comment: how about? "Buy it with no hard drive.  Then goto any vendor buy a hard drive or ssd and it won't come with an OS on it."  Or buy it "as-is" it then buy another hard drive or ssd separately, install that, and hide, burn, sell, or whatever the hard drive that came with it?

Comment: I'm with cybernard on this one. What's wrong with preinstalled Windows?